# Render at higher resolution than default framebuffer on OpenGL 2.1 without FBOs?

Tags: opengl

I am targeting an OpenGL 2.1 context which does not support framebuffers. My application originally used a texture framebuffer at double native resolution to perform shader effects and some basic supersampling. This texture is later drawn to the screen as a simple quad and can also be saved as a higher resolution image file.

Without framebuffer objects, I can use `glCopyTexSubImage2D` to copy pixels from the default framebuffer to a texture, however, I am unable to find a way to render my scene at a larger scale than initial given framebuffer.

Given my limitation on using framebuffer objects, and a smaller initial framebuffer size, is there any way to draw at a higher (2x scaled) resolution without additional FBOs?

One idea I had was to draw my scene in four higher resolution sections then stitch them together, but this seems overly complex and slow.

Comment: "draw my scene in four higher resolution sections then stitch them together" That's one [does](https://web.archive.org/web/20170117132313/http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html).

Comment: *"Given my limitation on using framebuffer objects"* - Why is that a limitation? The framebuffer is the target of rendering. If you want a higher resolution, then you have to use a greater buffer. It is possible to render to the texture directly, because a texture can be attached to the framebuffer. See [Framebuffer Object - Attaching Images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Attaching_Images)

Comment: @Rabbid76 It is a limitation because the hardware that will be running my application does not support them, not an artificial constraint. I am currently using framebuffers and understand how they work, the question is not regarding that.

Comment: @YorekB: "*but this seems overly complex and slow.*" Well, yeah. That's what happens when you're dealing with hardware that's more than *fifteen years old*. You have to use inefficient solutions because the hardware can't do better.

Comment: @YorekB every real world GPU supporting GL2.1 will most likely still support pbuffers, so you can use these.

Comment: @YorekB: *"overly complex"* should be as simple as calling your rendering routine four times with different projection matrices and a couple calls for copying the data. *"slow"* not necessarily. That would cost x4 vertex processing compared to the modern approach (assuming no culling is involved). However when rendering at x4 the screen resolution the fragment processing can easily be the bottleneck.

Comment: The joy of OpenGL 2.1 and old hardware...